# Which threads work method I need to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, threadpool

I have audio player application (c# .NET 4.0 WPF) that gets an audio-stream from the web and plays it. The app also displays waveforms and spectrums and saves the audio to local disk. It also does a few more things.

My quetion is when I recive a new byte packet from the web and I need to play them (and maybe write them to local disk etc.), do I need use threads? I try to do all the things with the main thread and it seems to work well.

I can work with threadpool for every bytes packet that I received in my connection. Would this be a reasonable approach?

Comment: that depends - you will have to think about concurrency but you will not block the UI - I would do this in a seperate thread but maybe not in more than one (one threadpool-task for complete download instead of one threadpool-task/thread for each packet)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks for the answer.  so even if the packets keep arriving always you recommend to start 1 thread and let it take care for the work?

Comment: yes downloading/assembling/etc. should not be done on the UI thread ...

Comment: I understand its not should be in the UI thread but how can I do it with 1 background thread? the packets arrive faster than the background work complete... Now i do this with background thread (from threadpool) for each packet, I understand its wrong but i dont know how to do it with 1 thread.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is a set of public types and APIs in the System.Threading and System.Threading.Tasks namespaces in the .NET Framework version 4. The purpose of the TPL is to make developers more productive by simplifying the process of adding parallelism and concurrency to applications. The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processors that are available. In addition, the TPL handles the partitioning of the work, the scheduling of threads on the ThreadPool, cancellation support, state management, and other low-level details.

Another option (if the operations you were performing were sufficiently long running) is the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). The BackgroundWorker component gives you the ability to execute time-consuming operations asynchronously ("in the background"), on a thread different from your application's main UI thread. To use a BackgroundWorker, you simply tell it what time-consuming worker method to execute in the background, and then you call the RunWorkerAsync method. Your calling thread continues to run normally while the worker method runs asynchronously. When the method is finished, the BackgroundWorker alerts the calling thread by firing the RunWorkerCompleted event, which optionally contains the results of the operation. This may not be the best option for you if you have many operations to undertake sequentially.

The next alternative that has been largely replaced by the TPL, is the [Thread Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx). This is not so easy to use at the TPL and you can do everything using the TPL as you can using the Thread Class (well almost) and the TPL is much more user friendly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 2 threads: in one you are downloading packets from web and putting them in queue(it can be UI thread if you are using async download operation) and in another thread you are analyzing queue and processing packets from it.

Comment: there is no need to use a thread for downloading - this is an asynchronous operation and if implemented correctly should not occupy a thread just to wait for the packets.

Comment: @Carsten König If one is using async operation - yes, of course.

Comment: thanks! can u tell me how to manage one thread that get new packet every time and to work? i want to register OnRecieve event in my connection and every time that data arrived to give the thread to handle this